# Bad video rendering with RecordMyDesktop

Tags: video, recordmydesktop, desktop-recording

I have used `recordmydesktop` for a while and it used to work very well, but lately it has begun to draw lines through the desktop on the rendered video.

How can I fix this, or what alternative software can I used to record my desktop?

**Update**
Fixed it by changing my resolution to 1360 / using kazam
But now my video comes out inclined!

[image: tilted screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Kazam](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/kazam/). You can install it from Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: thnaks it worked :) but i don't get a straight line in the recorded video :p have you an idea about that

Answer (score 2):

Solved by changing my resolution  from 1366 to 1360...

Just go to **Diplays** > **Resolution** > **1360**

But now I have another problem - the video recorded is not in a straight line!!

Comment: What do you mean by "the video recorded is not in straight line" ?

Comment: i have updated the question including a capture of what i get :)

Comment: http://s7.postimg.org/wo3ygchbv/inclined.png

Comment: @Serphiroth you can look to the link ;)

Comment: What a crazy idea.. change resolution... but it worked for me too!! :)Thanks to share this solution!

Answer (score 1):

I think [Kazam](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/kazam/) is the Best, you can install it via terminal, by typing :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kazam-team/unstable-series
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kazam python3-cairo python3-xlib
```

To remove it, do:

```
sudo apt-get remove kazam python3-cairo python3-xlib
```

Or you can install it from Ubuntu Software Center.

([Source](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-kazam-1-5-3-on-ubuntu-14-04-ubuntu-12-04-and-derivatives/))